# A word in between "lesser" and "greater"

Tags: single-word-requests

In many game systems (particularly fantasy or role-playing games), relative qualities or power levels are denoted by naming things using "lesser" or "greater". For example, in Dungeons and Dragons 3.5, there are weapon augmentation crystals, that might be named

- Least crystal of Arcane Steel
- Lesser crystal of Arcane Steel
- Greater crystal of Arcane Steel

etc.

It seems odd to me that there is a "least", a "lesser", and a "greater", but nothing in the middle. It makes sense that a "lesser" object is lesser than the "greater" one, and vice versa, but it seems strange to not have something in the middle. Of course one could argue that the one in the middle needs no such qualifier, but I was wondering - is there a word that can stand alongside words such as "lesser" and "greater" to denote that something is the "regular" version?

I thought of "common", but that strays into ideas of rarity, which is slightly different.

Comment: There's no "greatest". The maximum is the missing one.  "Standard" or "normal" may be the word you're looking for which means "regular".  Least, lesser, standard|normal, greater, greatest.

Comment: How about "Normal crystal of Arcane Steel"...

Comment: Regular old everyday run-of-the-mill crystal of Arcane Steel? Also, there doesn't *need* to be anything in the middle—the greater crystal is greater than the lesser crystals. If there were only two crystals, one would be lesser and the other would be greater.

Comment: The two species of Old World flamingos are the *lesser flamingo* and the *greater flamingo*. There's no plain flamingo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are right when you say that it could be argued that 'the one in the middle' needs no qualifier. And that is likely what would be best. However, if you felt the need to emphasize its 'normality', so to speak, then I believe words such as *standard*, *common*, *everyday*, *normal*, *conventional*, or *ordinary* would suffice.

Comment: Also, ***nominal***.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ***metaphorical realms*** you should explore.

Go *mathematical* and you can select from medium, median, average.

Choose *quality* and you have standard, paradigm,

If *height* is your metaphor mezzanine, base camp, Appenine.

Or there's *distance* arrow-flight, middling, stone's-throw.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that Lesser, Greater, etc. are similar to prefixes it's possible that there's no need for a word in between “lesser” and “greater.” Instead of using a word in between, you could use the absence of any word. You would do this because words like lesser or greater show that it's a lesser or greater version of it so when it's the normal version there is no need to specify.

For example:

- Lesser crystal of Arcane Steel
- Crystal of Arcane Steel
- Greater crystal of Arcane Steel

Other than that you could use the word "normal."

For example:

- Lesser crystal of Arcane Steel
- Normal Crystal of Arcane Steel
- Greater crystal of Arcane Steel

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I will venture that Skyrim used the *petty, lesser, common, greater*, and *grand* system.

I generally use *weak* or *feeble, lesser, greater*, and *grand*; however, if I am making a system of ranking based on strength/power, I will often use *lesser, minor*, and *greater*.

Comment: Which word in particular would you offer for the "word in between"? (None of those that you mentioned seem to fit that perfectly.)